# Why won't my joined meshes work together?

Tags: armature, parent, pose-mode

I'm creating two hands (duplicated) and join them to a torso for IMVU (some chatting game). I parent the joined hands+torso to the armature (an entire skeleton), but only one of the hands stick to the torso. The second hand, although both are joined together, deforms completely.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNn0R.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWnaX.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXegf.png

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, but if the main focus is on the hands, wouldn't it be better to make screenshots wide enough so that both hands are visible all the time? And from what I see they both look the same, so I don't know which is the one that has an issue. But if there is a difference: since the hands are duplicated as you said, could it be that both hands are moved by the same bone which makes one behave correctly while the other is weirdly deforming?